# External gpu enclosure work?

Tags: laptop, gpu, external

I am wondering if this external gpu enclosure will work with my Dell Inspiron i3 3000 laptop?
If I just plug it in to the usb port will it still be recognized?

https://www.amazon.ca/N-ORANIE-Graphics-Extension-Powered-Capacitors/dp/B077KS8GBF/

Comment: No; it’s not compatible

Comment: This is not an enclosure? They do exist, and they use Thunderbolt. If your laptop supports Thunderbolt, you can get an eGPU enclosure.

Comment: This isn't. This is one of those bitcoin mining apparatus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it won't.

Its a device that breaks out an internal PCIe x1 of some flavour via this unit.

[image]

It is not a real usb port on either end. Some would consider this an unholy abomination created by damned souls, for damned souls, and is an affront before man, deities, and standards boards. I might have strong opinions on its intended use.

Then misuses a USB cable to carry the signal out to a  break out board which will take in a PCIe x16 card running at x1. This is simply because these cables have the right number of connections (and of course, by standards A to A cables shouldn't be a thing. This is a case of two wrongs making a greater wrong). Just cause you can, means you should. Someone did.

This is meant for bitcoin/crypto mining boards with a ludicious number of x1 slots, so you can plug in a bunch of video cards on an open rack and waste power and generate heat.

You will risk damaging your laptop by plugging this into a laptop, especially if you are supplying power.

Fundamentally this is a very bad idea and you should not do this. In *theory* there's units that will break out NVMe or mini PCIe with a adaptor replacing the above, but generally that's going to be a different story. In any case you won't be plugging it into an actual, standards compliant USB port.

Comment: PCIe x1 requires at least 8 wires. USB 3.0 cables have 9 and are widely available, so these adapters use them to reduce costs.

Comment: 9? 8 + ground I guess?  I distinctly recall 8. Also these are cheaper and easier to abuse than USB C one would guess, and available in quantity.

Comment: This product would also be impossible to use with a laptop of unknown design, considering it requires the use of that USB port, and laptops don't typically have any sort of expansion ability, for additional cards. It serves a purpose in a lab setting or in a benchmark setup.

Comment: Its not a USB port.

Comment: USB 3.0 adds an additional ground for 3.0 signal lines. "Blue" connectors have 5 new pins in the back: TX differential pair, RX differential pair and this extra GND. Actually I'm not sure if it's independent from the 2.0 GND, so you may be correct.